# Backbone, what happens exactly when you call render() mupliple times

Tags: backbone.js

I have seen examples of people calling this.render() when listening to changes to the model.

```
initialize : function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change:someAttribute", this.render());
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change:someOtherAttribute", this.render());
}
```

if the render() function is creating a view from some underscore template and attaching it to the html document, what happens to the existing HTML that was attached originally?  If I had a drop down selected and some text in one of the view's fields, why aren't they reset to the default values when the render() function is called?

Comment: Are you sure you've seen them calling `this.listenTo(..., this.render())` rather than `this.listenTo(..., this.render)`?

Comment: oh, I was under the impression that `this.render` and `this.render()` were the same thing, they are both calling the function on the object...

Comment: Not in JavaScript, `this.render` is just a reference to the function whereas `this.render()` calls the `render` method on `this`. They're very different things.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to your DOM depends on what you do in your render method, if you replace a whole elements html with

```
this.$el.html( _.template( htmlString, data ) );
```

of if you just append to it

```
this.$el.append( _.template( htmlString, data ) );
```

There are different scenarios based on how you set up your app, but i think you will mostly have the render method replacing the whole element, and then you will have an event listener bound to collection changes for example, so if a model is added to the collection you append a sub view to the main views el.

```
var view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: '#view1div',
 initialize: function(){
  this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
  this.collection.bind('add', this.addElement, this);
 },
 render: function(){
  this.$el.html( '<ul id="list"></ul>' );
 },
 addElement: function(){
  $('#list').append( '<li>something</li>' );
 }
});
```